# Looking for a way to improve performance on retrieving a large number of records in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an inherited code in where it retrieves a list of person object from a relational database via spring data jpa framework.

There is an interface `PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,UUID>` in the application. I noticed that `findAll` method from its parent interface pulls data however due to a large number of records, it takes a quite a while to load it.

I am trying to somehow optimize its poor performance but I don't have much clue at this point. Beside I am new to spring data jpa and have very basic understanding of it.

Is there any good recommendation you could provide for this matter? I greatly appreciate it.

update:

I realized later that the Person entity has multiple `@OneToMany` relationships with other entities. I noticed lazy loading was turned off. Once I enabled lazy loading `@OneToMany(fetchtype.lazy)`, I noticed a huge delta in its performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination with *Pageable*.

Look at it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts